# calculating complexity sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 6.7 and java as language

I tested complexity and found some keywords which should be incrementing the complexity is not increment the value of complexity. Here some of the keywords:

1. ***case***
2. ***return***
3. ***throw*** (this one a little hard to test, I create two function where has throw and the other has no throw, and I found out that it always increment the value of cognitive wether there is throw or not. So I try to create try catch and state throw e, but it is not increment the value of cognitive)

And some keywords which not state can increment the value of cognitive but increment the value anyway:

1. ***else if***
2. ***else*** (increment only the **cognitive complexity**, but does not increment the cyclomatic complexity)
3. ***function*** (increments only the **cyclomatic complexity**, but does not increment the cognitive complexity. I am a little bit confused about this, because there is no statement, only example)
4. ***switch*** (increment only the **cognitive complexity**, but does not increment the cyclomatic complexity)

Can someone help me to confirm if I miss something or is it right?

Comment: I don't understand what is the question asked. could you clarify the question ? You can also have a look at how those computation are implemented : cognitive:  https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/ast/visitors/CognitiveComplexityVisitor.java and cyclomatic : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/ast/visitors/ComplexityVisitor.java

Comment: Moreover, please specify the version of SonarJava analyzer you are using.

Comment: Sonarqube version 6.7 and language is java

What I'm asking is wether it is right or not because it is not consentient with sonarqube document https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Complexity

Comment: example : return is stated will increment value to complexity, but when I test it, it didn't increment the value

Comment: what is the SonarJava version?

Comment: SonarJava version is 4.15.0.12310